# generate URL with @Url.Action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a question about Url.Action.

My position is on http://localhost/User/Edit and for some case I have to generate a link with a javascript function, so it would be like this:

```
 return '<a href="@Url.Action("Group","Edit")/' +myParameterInJavascript +'>link</a>';
```

If I look to the link, it would be ok, I got: http://localhost/Group/Edit/ParameterFromJs

But, then when my current position is http://localhost/Group/Edit/ParameterFromJs
and I generate the same link again, the URL will become :

http://localhost/Group/Edit/ParameterFromJs/ParameterFromJs

Why don't I just get the url http://localhost/Group/Edit/ParameterFromJs?
Why was my action Edit/ParameterFromJs, and not just Edit?

Can you give me some hint or tips? Thanks in advance

UPDATE : 
This is my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("group-edit",
            "Group/Edit/{groupName}",
            new
            {
                controller = "Group",
                action = "Edit"
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using routing:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Group", "Edit", new { id = "__id__" })'.replace('__id__', myParameterInJavascript);
return '<a href="' + url + '">link</a>';
```

Comment: @Rivera, how does your route definition look like? Do you have the default route? Update your routes so that you have an id token in the url as the default one.

Comment: actually I wrote the route, am I wrong on wrote route?see update please

Comment: @Rivera, ok, so you defined a route with the `{groupName}` token. You can use it now: `new { groupName = "__id__" })`.

Comment: aha it worked, thanks a lot :) , I think it was on Url.Action, I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like that:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Group", new { EditParam = myParameterInJavascript })">
```

When You put parameter use "?" not "/"

```
 http://localhost/Group/Edit?ParameterFromJs
```